# Laravel Eloquent making select on whereHas()

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent, orm, relationship

How can I select on `whereHas()` some columns in relation.

My current query looks like as it follows

```
Location::select(['title'])
->withCount(['job' => function($q) {
          return $q->where('language_id', 1)->whereNull('deleted_at');
        }])->whereHas('country', function ($q) {
            return $q->where('id', '=', 80);
        })->get();
```

and I tried

```
Location::select(['title', 'id as value'])->withCount(['job' => function($q) {
          return $q->where('language_id', 1)->whereNull('deleted_at');
        }])->whereHas('country', function ($q) {
            return $q->select('title', 'iso3')->where('id', '=', 80);
        })->get();
```

but nothing is getting returned on `country` relation. How do I refactor this query to get it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`whereHas()` doesn't eager load the relation, only filters results based on it. To eager load, use `with()`.

```php
Location::with('country:id,title,iso3')
    ->select(['title', 'id as value', 'country_id'])
    ->withCount(['job' => function($q) {
        $q->where('language_id', 1)->whereNull('deleted_at');
    }])
    ->whereHas('country', function ($q) {
        $q->where('id', '=', 80);
    })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback if I remove select than I get the fields what I requested but somehow with select on main Table will return null as result.

Comment: you have to make sure you select the needed foreign key from the main table `locations` otherwise it potentially can't match up the related models to it

Comment: I removed the alias but still the same result

Comment: You need to include the foreign key lining the locations record to country record in the select. And I guess was wrong about the alias. Say for eg if **country_id** is the foreign key on locations table linking it to record on countries table - include **country_id** in the select